# SpagoBI: End user customized front page

Tags: fiware, spagobi

I have created a new user, with a new role and I want to configure the user front page. 
I added a document that the admin created, but when I login as my new user, I see a blanc page, I can't see the page content :(
What have I missed, is there another privileges that I need to set to my user to be able to see the document created by the admin?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to enter as admin and then:
1. enter the details of the user's role and enable required functionalities (documents browser, my data, my analysis, ...);
2. enter Menu configuration and define menu items for user's role.
As an alternative, you can develop an external web application using REST API.
Best regards
Davide

Comment: Remember that the user home page is the first menu item